# Add Employee in File

Tags: java, file, api, file-io, io

I would like to add a employee in file.  

Class employee /*getters and setters*/

Class EmployeeStore

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class EmployeeStore {

    ArrayList<Employee> emp ;
    public EmployeeStore()
    {
        emp = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    }

    public void ajouter(Employee employee)
    {
        emp.add(employee);
    }
}
```

Class Main

```
import java.io.*;
public class EmployeeTest {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     EmployeeStore employee = new EmployeeStore();

    try {
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:/Users/Akram/Documents/akram.txt")) ;
            Employee str = new Employee("Akram","Khalifa");
            employee.ajouter(str);
            StringBuilder  stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuilder.append( str );
           // out.write(str);
            out.close();
            System.out.println("File created successfuly");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

 }
}
```

The file created but i don't find anything in file (file empty).

Comment: the line where you write to the file is commented out, you will probably also need to flush the output buffer prior to closing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed to dump your stringBuilder into  your file using the fileWriter i assume that your Employee has a firstName and lastName Attributes
The main class should be coded this way :

```
  public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
             EmployeeStore employee = new EmployeeStore();

            try {

                    Employee str = new Employee("Akram","Khalifa");
                    employee.ajouter(str);
                    StringBuilder  stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    stringBuilder.append( "firstName : "+str.getFirstName () + " --LastName :"+str.getLastName());
                    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:/Users/Akram/Documents/akram.txt") ;
//write down ur employee in the file 
                    writer.write(stringBuilder.toString());;
                    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(writer) ;

                    out.close();
                    System.out.println("File created successfuly");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided is very messy. The stringBuilder part does nothing at all.
Obviously an empty file is created, because you've opened a writer to a file, however you've never wrote anything to it.
When you say "I would like to add a employee in file", it means you're trying to serialize employee object. This can be achieved by many ways. 
You can try java's native serialization with ObjectOutputStream (also mind the difference between Writers and Streams).
An example can be found in javadoc: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `// out.write(str);` with `out.write(stringBuilder.toString());` and override `toString()` method of Employee class so that you see some relevant info about your Employee class in the created file.

Answer (score 0):

There is no place where you acutally write something to file. You can try this

`out.append(stringBuilder.toString());`

in place where you have

`// out.write(str);`

Answer (score 0):

> The file created but i don't find anything in file (file empty).

```
// out.write(str);
```

You are creating empty file and closing it without writing any content to it.

As per [Api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write%28java.lang.String%29), write() takes String, so you need
convert String Builder to String before writing

```
out.write(str.toString())
```

will solve it.